# trigger on scroll past DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, vertical-scrolling

I am trying to trigger actions when the user scrolls into various DOM elements (I need this to be responsive for various screen sizes). I first get the locations of the respective elements with `offset().top` then I calculate the location of the scroll with `scrollTop()`. It works somewhat but the action is triggered too far past the start of the DOM element. I have removed all padding and margins...

```
var hT = $('#bioAG').offset().top;
var hT2 = $('#bioTM').offset().top;
var hT3 = $('#contact').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function () {
  var ws = $(window).scrollTop()          
  if (ws > hT) {
    $("#bioAG").addClass("fade-in");
      } else if (ws > hT2){
       $("#bioTM").addClass("fade-in");
         } else if (ws > hT3)  {
           $("#contact").addClass("fade-in");
             } else {console.log('none');};
```

}) `

Comment: logically on scroll (every once in a while) you should recalculate your variables....

Comment: I guess I am struggling to understand why that would be the case if the viewport isn't resized. Why would the position of the DOM elements change if they already exist when the page is first called?

Comment: Cause: 1: you scroll the page, 2: you resize the window, 3: scroll and JS is now messed up (well... unless your elements are always at fixed NNpx height - which  I guess is less probable.)

Comment: True, they do change a bit now that I look at them for the length of the page. I still have the original problem on the very first DOM element but thanks for pointing that out, I am sure it will be an issue further down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On scroll (load and resize) calculate the `.top` position of every `data-fadein` elements.
`filter()` then returning the elements which top position is less than the window height - and add on that elements the desired class.

```js
var $ele = $("[data-fadein]"),
    $win = $(window);

function fadeInEl() {

  var h = $win.height();

  $ele.filter(function() {
    return this.getBoundingClientRect().top < h;
  }).addClass("fade-in");

}


// Call the above function on:
$win.on("load resize scroll", fadeInEl);
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
html,body{height:100%;margin:0;}


[data-fadein] {
  height:100vh;
  opacity:0;
  transition: 2s;
}
.fade-in {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-fadein id="bioAG"   style="background:#0af">ag</div>
<div data-fadein id="bioTM"   style="background:#f0a">tm</div>
<div data-fadein id="contact" style="background:#0fa">contact</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Thanks for the great-looking code. It works quite well all the way down to the mobile breakpoints, where I think the 100vh and the varying text lengths of my divs are the main obstacles (I intend to try and make all of my div texts more uniform). The code definitely put me on a much better track, though, and I learned some new things to boot.

Comment: @eabates the div size would be best 100vh but it can be taller it does not matters. - I've seen now an issue talking about heights... will edit in a minute

Comment: Ok I will try adjusting the 100vh with media queries, thanks.

Comment: @eabates edited my answer. Now height really does not matters. You can let the content dictate the element height...

Comment: hm, I needed the `last` before `addClass` on the filter (otherwise I had no fade in). I think 130vh will work for mobile, now I am just figuring out how to do media queries with data-attributes...